# Need help on SQL Qyery

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've been referred to this site by one of my friends; working with SQL query that's already built in (not really good at it and trying to learn); our Fiscal Year ended on Sept. 30 and new Fiscal Year took place (Oct to Sept). When pulling the report using the saved query; I've found that some of the data are missing as it is pulling the current Fiscal Year's data.

I'm wondering where exactly can I tweak in to pull the data for FY 2019! Here are the queries:

```
declare @FFY    int
set     @FFY = dbo.ufn_GetFederalFiscalYear(getdate())
```

Any help would be great. Thank you :-)
Mansur

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server? (That code won't run on both.)

Comment: Whats this `dbo.ufn_GetFederalFiscalYear1()` a stored proceedure/function? If so it would probably be more use to see the contents of it rather than just how you call it please

Comment: If the problem is the value that `dbo.ufn_GetFederalFiscalYear` is returning is wrong, we're going to **need** the DDL for that function. Otherwise this is like asking a a mechanic to fix your car's engine, but telling them they aren't allowed to look under to bonnet (hood).

Comment: Assuming the function returns the `CURRENT Federal FY` by your `FY calendar`, it would be `2020` and you want to return `FY 2019` data, just subtract 1 from the `@FFY` variable. Or am I missing something else here.

Comment: Agreed here; you'd need to see exactly what the function is doing, so you could diagnose it correctly.  You can view function details, right?

Comment: I'm using SQL Server Mgmt. Studio 2014. I'm getting most of the data but need only the Fiscal Year 2019 data

Comment: The version of Management Studio has little to do with the version of SQL Server you're using, @MansurAhmed . Especially when SSMS is free and the latest version is 2019 (which supports SQl Server 2008-2019).

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @FFY    int
set     @FFY = 2019
```

Comment: Thank you so much; didn't know "this is how simple it was"! Appreciate all of your input and help :-)